# Hexagonal Pascal's Triangle with Blank Rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to modify [this Pascal's Triangle example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/pascal-triangle/) to allow blank rows at the bottom for students to fill out:

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialCoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newdimen\R
\R=.4cm
\newcommand\mycolor{white}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8pt]
        \def\rows{9}
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\rows}
        {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(-60:{sqrt(3)*\R*\k})}]
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ystart{\rows-\k}
                \foreach \n in {0,...,\ystart}
                {
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\newn{\n+\k}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=0}{\def\mycolor{pink}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=1}{\def\mycolor{yellow}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=2}{\def\mycolor{blue}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=3}{\def\mycolor{green}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=8 \AND \n < 4}{\def\mycolor{red}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=9 \AND \n = 3}{\def\mycolor{purple}}{}
                    \begin{scope}[shift={(-120:{sqrt(3)*\R*\n})}]
                        \draw[top color=\mycolor!20,bottom color=\mycolor!60] 
                         (30:\R) \foreach \x in {90,150,...,330} {
                            -- (\x:\R)}
                            -- cycle (90:0)
                               node {\tiny $\mathbf{\binomialCoefficient{\newn}{\k}}$};
                    \end{scope}
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I was able to get rid of the color and make a custom variable `\rows` for number of rows. However I did not figure out how to remove the text for the last three rows. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the node text based on the value of `\newn`:

[image]

Define which is the last non-blank row:

```
\def\BlankRowAfter{6}
```

and then

```
\ifnum\newn>\BlankRowAfter\relax
  \def\NodeText{}%
\else
  \def\NodeText{\tiny $\mathbf{\binomialCoefficient{\newn}{\k}}$}%
\fi
```

determines `\NodeText` to be blank if needed.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} \pagecolor{white}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialCoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newdimen\R
\R=.4cm
\newcommand\mycolor{white}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8pt]
        \def\rows{9}
        \def\BlankRowAfter{6}
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\rows}
        {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(-60:{sqrt(3)*\R*\k})}]
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ystart{\rows-\k}
                \foreach \n in {0,...,\ystart}
                {
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\newn{\n+\k}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=0}{\def\mycolor{pink}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=1}{\def\mycolor{yellow}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=2}{\def\mycolor{blue}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=3}{\def\mycolor{green}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=8 \AND \n < 4}{\def\mycolor{red}}{}
                    % \ifthenelse{\k=9 \AND \n = 3}{\def\mycolor{purple}}{}
                    \ifnum\newn>\BlankRowAfter\relax
                        \def\NodeText{}%
                    \else
                        \def\NodeText{\tiny $\mathbf{\binomialCoefficient{\newn}{\k}}$}%
                    \fi
                    \begin{scope}[shift={(-120:{sqrt(3)*\R*\n})}]
                        \draw[top color=\mycolor!20,bottom color=\mycolor!60] 
                         (30:\R) \foreach \x in {90,150,...,330} {
                            -- (\x:\R)}
                            -- cycle (90:0)
                               node {\NodeText};
                    \end{scope}
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the key system that TikZ comes with.

In the code below, three styles each get tried for the path:

- `every binom path = {k}{n}`,
  `binom path row n` and
  `binom path col k` as well as
- `every binom node = {k}{n}`,
  `binom node row n` and
  `binom node col k`.

This allows you define styles for specific rows or columns but also for each element specifically by testing `#1` and `#2` inside the `every binom ....` styles. In this case, we set `binom node row 7`, `… 8` and `… 9` so that the `node contents` is set empty and noone else can reset it again by disabling the `node contents` key.

I've also added an expandable eTeX evaluation of the binomial coefficient.

There's also the `regular polygon` node which we can use for drawing the hexagons but it doesn't make it much easier.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\usepackage{libertine}
\newcommand*\binomialCoefficient[2]{% #1 = n, #2 = k
  \expanded{\noexpand\binomialCoefficientRec{\pgfintmin{#1-#2}{#2}}}{1}{#1}{1}}
\newcommand*\binomialCoefficientRec[4]{% #1 = k, #2 = i, #3 = n, #4 = result
  \ifnum#2>#1 #4\else
    \expanded{\noexpand\binomialCoefficientRec{#1}{\pgfinteval{#2+1}}{#3}
      {\pgfintdivtruncate{#4*(#3+1-(#2))}{#2}}}\fi}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  thick, no text/.style={node contents=, node contents/.code=},
  every binom node/.style 2 args={node contents={$\binomialCoefficient{#2}{#1}$}},
  no binom text/.style={binom node row #1/.style={no text}},
  no binom text/.list={7, 8, 9}
]
\foreach \n in {0,..., 9}
  \foreach \k in {0, ..., \n}
    \draw[
      shift={([y=(-120:1)]\k,\n)}, every binom path/.try={\k}{\n},
      binom path row \n/.try, binom path col \k/.try]
        node[node contents=, every binom node/.try={\k}{\n},
             binom node row \n/.try, binom node col \k/.try]
        plot[sharp cycle, samples at={0, ..., 5}](30+\x*60:sqrt 3/3);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]